# Workers forget their actions!

Tags: civilization-5, linux

When I assign a worker to do a task, like build a mine, he will ask for an action again next turn, when the mine hasn't been finished yet.

Why do they do that? This appears to be a Linux-only thing, as it works fine on Windows 7. Is this some hidden settings or so? Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Be sure no enemy units are nearby or the worker will stop its current work and ask for an action to be taken.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I am playing a game at the moment and there is no enemy units to be seen.

Comment: There was an old bug in Civ 5 that caused workers to constantly think there was an enemy nearby.  Do you have any of the expansions, or just vanilla Civ 5?

Comment: @JasonBerkan I have the Mongols DLC, but besides that it's Vanilla. It should be updated though, maybe Linux just gets an older version? Is there somewhere I can check my version? I went to the steam properties dialog but I can't seem to find anything there.

Comment: My initial guess is that it is the same bug, unfixed in the Linux version for some reason.  It was quite annoying, to say the least.

Comment: This [is the bug in question](http://steamcommunity.com/app/8930/discussions/0/882965118557457763/#p1). If you read it all, it seems to happen with captured workers and workers that were on "auto" improve and than used manually. Unsure if any of the tips in that thread will help you.

Comment: [Some more infos can be found on civfanatics forums](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=479499)

Comment: Happens with me too sometimes (I play on Windows) . Still haven't found out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug present in older versions of Civilization.

The only way to fix it on a Linux system is by buying all of the expansions.

Comment: Is this answer Linux-specific, or is the only way to fix it on all platforms buying all the expansions?

Comment: @cbirdsong I don't have this problem on Windows, so I can imagine it is a Linux-only solution. Do you have this issue on a Windows system?